# Modify Path Access Restrictions

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

for personal usage, I downloaded an openstreetmap map (as a *.osm) and try to modify it using  the Josm editor.
I want to trace a path in the card I walked and want to remove unnecessary things from this map. Other paths are highlighted, because they are access-restricted. This is saved in the preset `Highways/Streets/Road Restrictions`.

[image: Two Presets on the path] This is how Josm displays what I mean.

How can I delete this preset or hide the highlighting? I don't want to delete the whole path, though.

For better illustration, path I mean goes from the upper-left corner to the right and is highlighted by the application in blue.  [image: Map]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you want to remove the `vehicle=no` tag from e.g. this way? https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/42711752

Comment: @scai Not exactly the tag, but the presets. There are two presets assigned to the path: `Road restrictions` and `path`. Since the road restriction causes the highlighting of the path, I want to remove it. I don't want to modify the online version of the map, it's just for a map I'm creating for myself.

Comment: In OSM there are just tags, no presets. Presets exist only inside the editor, not in your `.osm` file. The editor automatically assigns them depending on the *tags*. You can't remove or add a preset, you can only remove or add tags.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Modified the `vehicle` tag.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ready made paint styles that you can use in JOSM to display the map data and you can even create new styles by using the MapCSS language. Below are instructions how you can remove the blue highlight but please, see https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Styles for further details on the JOSM styles, how to use them, how to create them and even how to share a style to others for use if you like.

To hide the highlighting for the blue route follow the instructions below:

1. Store the following code, for example, to a `non_highlight_routes.mapcss` file:

```
    meta {
      title: "Hide route relations";
      version: "0.1";
      description: "Hide the route relations";
      author: "Your name";
    }

    relation[type=route] > way::route { width: 0; opacity: 0; }
```

2. In the JOSM, open the preferences dialog from the edit menu. As shown in the image below, go to the map settings and paint styles tab and add the new style via the plus button. Make sure that the new style is below the JOSM default style in the list and then press the OK button to close the preferences dialog.

   [image: JOSM map paint style preferences]
3. Now when you view the data in JOSM the route is not highlighted anymore:

[image: JOSM map style routes hidden]

Similarly to removing the blue higlight for the route relation, you can create map paint style that shows the map exactly as you like. If you create a post card style you could share it via the above mentioned [JOSM style wiki page](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Styles) for anyone to use!